# In Laravel 4 unit-test, how to set cookie in request?

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, cookies, laravel-4

In my Laravel 4 app, I wish to test that a particular endpoint detects and responds correctly to cookies in the request. So, in my unit-test, I wish to set a cookie into the request and then perform the standard assertions on the response.

My call in the unit-test is of the form:

```
$response = $this->client->request($method, $endpoint, $params, $files, $server);
```

where I have specified my correct values for `$method`, `$endpoint`, `$params`, and empty `$files` and `$server`.

I have tried many variations, placing the cookie values inside `$params` or `$server` under various keys, but so far, no luck seeing the cookies show up in the controller under `Cookie:get('myname)`.

How do I set a cookie with name 'myname' and value 'myvalue' in the request in a unit-test?

**Update:**

I imagine I could simply add a header to the request:

```
Cookie: myname=myvalue
```

but I gotta believe that there is a more Laravel-like way of doing it.

**Update 2:**

The above did *not* work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like we can do the following in a test that extends `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase`:

```
$this->client->getCookieJar()->set(
    new \Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Cookie('myname', 'myvalue')
);
```

The cookie will then be exposed in the controller via the standard:

```
$cookie = Cookie::get('myname'); // $cookie gets 'myvalue'
```

(via [Laravel.io](http://laravel.io/forum/03-23-2014-unit-testing-mocking-call-to-cookieget))

Comment: I get this error: `ErrorException: Undefined property: ExampleTest::$client`

Comment: Does your `ExampleTest` extend `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase` ?

Comment: Yes, it does extend that class.

Answer (score 1):

> EDIT: THIS ONLY WORKS FOR LARAVEL 5.2 OR GREATER

You can set Cookies with the call() method shown in the [Documentation for TestCase](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.html#method_call)

I used something similar recently. Here is an example:

```
$cookies = ['cookie_name' => 'cookie_value'];
$response = $this->call("get", 'target/url/for/request', [], $cookies);
```

Here is an [additional issue thread](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/12032) on the Laravel Framework Github where someone had some confusion on how to call this. This further cemented my knowledge. Hope this helps!

EDIT:

There seems to be an issue with laravel dropping cookies it cannot decrypt. Be wary of this. [Here is a Link](https://laravel.io/forum/04-14-2015-how-to-set-cookies-during-unit-test) to someone encountering this issue.

Their suggested solution (in case this link dies):

> It seems that the problem is cookie encryption. Laravel will delete the cookies that it can't decrypt. As test cookies is not created by laravel (I simply use an array to test cookies as seen in the previous post), they are not encrypted and they will be deleted. I can think of two solutions for this problem.
>
> 1. Simply remove cookie middleware from the list in app/Http/Kernel.php. All cookies will be sent to and received from the client as they are. If you don't need encryption or you want to read some cookies in the client side this is a nice solution.
> 2. Edit middleware so that it won't encrypt or decrypt cookies during testing. Just add a code to handle function that checks the environment and continues without doing anything if environment is testing. This middleware is in Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookie.php. So a framework update will undo your editing in this file. If you need encrpytion this is your only solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reference and the detailed explanation. :D Sadly, it appears that the method you cite doesn't appear in Laravel 4, making its first appearance in v5.2.0 via the trait `Concerns\MakesHttpRequests`. Glad they added it, but in Laravel 4, looks like we're still stuck with the `getCookieJar()` workaround.

Comment: @DavidWeinraub You're right. I will edit to make this clear. But I will leave the answer up for people who are running more recent versions of laravel.

Answer (score 1):

I did a test for a functionality that needed something very similar. I did my test using the `$this->call()` function:

```
$this->call($method, $url, $parameters = [], $cookies = ["name"=> Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::encryptString("Leonardo")], $files = [], $server = [], $content = null);
```

If you need to see more or less how it works, just look for this file:

```
Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference and the detailed explanation. :D Sadly, it appears that the method you cite doesn't appear in Laravel 4, making its first appearance in v5.2.0 via the trait Concerns\MakesHttpRequests. Glad they added it, but in Laravel 4, looks like we're still stuck with the getCookieJar() workaround.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put cookie variable with return response then it will work

code will look like

$response->withCookie(cookie('name', 'value', $minutes));

return $response;

Comment: That's how you send a cookie back to the client with his response. I need a way to set a cookie in the *request* so my code can read/process it.

Comment: no , my knowledge says that laravel sets cookie only if it is attached with return .
in your case you can use that variable in your code and then send variable with cookie in response if it is to be set (according to your code flow / conditions )

Answer (score 0):

As `Noah Gary` wrote, be careful because since version 5.2 Laravel comes with a default middleware in the web group that will reset all unencrypted cookies passed in any `$request->call()` function. The cookies header won't be reset but all cookie values will be set to `null` by default.

Check `Kernel.php` and you'll find `\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class` in the `web` middleware group. You can simply disable it but it's not advised.

If you don't want to call `$request->disableCookieEncryption()` everytime, as a permanent solution you can simply redefine the `isDisabled()` method in `App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies.php` to ignore cookies encryption during unit testing.

Here is the implementation I made for Laravel 6.x, it should work on earlier versions too.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies as Middleware;

class EncryptCookies extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The names of the cookies that should not be encrypted.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        //
    ];

    public function isDisabled($name)
    {
        if (app()->runningUnitTests()) {
            return true;    // Disable cookies encryption/decryption during unit testing
        }

        return parent::isDisabled($name);
    }
}
```